# verbal English, oral English, and spoken English

Tags: difference

Do verbal English, oral English, and spoken English mean the same? For example, "My ... English is not good".

I use them interchangeably, but I might be wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The most common terms for these concepts are *spoken English* and *written English*.

Let's see how common each of your three choices is.  I searched the [*Corpus of Contemporary American English (COCA)*](http://corpus2.byu.edu/coca/) for each term and wrote down how many results there were:

```
  search term         results
  ---------------     -----------
  spoken english      54
  oral english        20
  verbal english      0
```

These results confirm my intuition, which tell me that *spoken English* is the most common form, and that *oral English* is still acceptable but is somewhat less common.

*Verbal* is sometimes used to mean "spoken rather than written", but it's not always used that way, and in this context I'm not sure it'd be understood.  (When I was younger, I took a standardized test with a "verbal" section.  It tested my written English skills, not my spoken English skills!)  I'd avoid saying *verbal English*.

Comment: +1. *Verbal* is widely used to mean "oral" or "spoken". I had a friend who worked for a large corporation where the rule was "NVO" - "No Verbal Orders", meaning don't do anything unless you're told *in writing* to do it. But this is asking for trouble: "verbal" should be used to mean "having to do with words" or, in linguistics, "having to do with verbs".

Comment: Once upon a time there were "oral examiners" of English, only recently they've been renamed "speaking examiners"!:)

Comment: Thanks! "spoken English" or "speaking English"?

Comment: @Tim "Speaking English" is an activity.  "Spoken English" is a kind of English.

Comment: I always avoid "oral", because it can be used in sexual context. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Tim If you like.  You don't have to avoid it, but if you do at least you'll never cause any confusion :-)